# Query is not checking database AdvID itself and delete

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

i want the query to check database AdvID itself and delete when page is loaded. Why am i getting this error call "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function 'DeleteByDate' expects parameter '@AdvID', which was not supplied." Shouldnt it check the database itself and delete? why do i have to supply it with AdvID? Here is my page_load code

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Generate auto ID
    SqlDataAdapter sad = new SqlDataAdapter("Select isnull(max(cast(AdvID as int)),0)+1 from Advertisement", sqlCon);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sad.Fill(dt);
    advertismentIdTb.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();

    //PageLoadValidations
    statusTb.Text = "1";
    endDateTb.Attributes["min"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    btnDelete.Enabled = false;
    btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
    Image1.Visible = false;

    //Delete from DB Condition (EndDate)
    if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteByDate", sqlCon);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCon.Close();

    //Show GridView
    FillGridView();
}
```

And here is my script

```sql
ALTER PROC [dbo].[DeleteByDate]
@AdvID int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = GETDATE() -- to get current date

    -- Assuming that Advertisement table has the column EndDate
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Advertisement a WHERE a.EndDate < @CurrentDate )
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE a SET a.Status = 0
        FROM Advertisement a
        WHERE a.AdvID = @AdvID  
    END 
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking for a query which will delete all advertisements that ended earlier than right now?  Your current query is checking if there are any advertisements that ended before right now then deleted the one with the ID you pass in.

Based on the above assumption, try the following query:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[DeleteByDate]
AS BEGIN

    UPDATE  a 
    SET     a.Status = 0
    FROM    Advertisement a
    WHERE   a.EndDate < GETDATE()

END
```

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Please mark as answer and / or upvote